# Internal Direct Sum of Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, direct-sum

**Exercise** Let $V$ be any vector space with $T:V \to V$. Suppose $M_1 =\{v \in V: T(v) = v\}$, $M_2 = \{v \in V: T(v) = -v\}$ are eigenspaces of $V$ and $T^2(v) = v$, show that $V = M_1 + M_2$, i.e. show that

$$\forall \, v \in V, v = m_1+m_2 \hspace{0.3cm} m_1 \in M_1, m_2 \in M_2$$

So $v$ can be written as the sum of objects from $M_1$ and $M_2$.

*Attempt.*

Let $v \in V$. We have that $T^2(v) = v$.

Perhaps we could consider $v = v+0 = v +(v+(-v))$. Then

$$T(v) = T(v) +T(v) + T(-v) = 2T(v) - T(v)$$

I'm not sure how to utilize $T^2(v) = v$ here. How can we show that $v$ is the sum of two objects from $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively when $v$ is chosen arbitrarily?

Comment: Hint: consider $v\pm Tv$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @paul garrett hinted :

The element $\frac{v+T(v)}{2} \in V $ and also $\frac{v+T(v)}{2} \in M_1 $ because $T(\frac{v+T(v)}{2} ) =  \frac{v+T(v)}{2} 
$ given that $T^2(v) = v$.

$\frac{v-T(v)}{2} \in M_2$ for the same reason.

For any $v \in V$ then these choices are fine.